# Hard Edge won't smooth with Sub Div

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

Doing some modeling with Subsurface Div on and there is a hard edge that simply will not smooth.
See imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3KWs.jpg

I've tried all of the following:

-Verified no dup. verts

-Verified Normals Outside & In

-Checked for Clear Edge

-Tried smoothing Object

-Loop cut and added additional loop for potential topology issue...

I'm out of ideas, anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: I believe I have self resolved this by increasing the Auto Smooth angle to 60.....

Answer (score 1):

With some trouble shooting it appears this could be fixed by increasing/adjusting auto smooth. Per the blender manual the auto smooth angle appears to have a threshold that if broken will consider the edge sharp.